# How can I search for values in three columns, but return rows that don't match all?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have two tables, say A and B. I wish to compare three or more columns in both tables and to return any rows in table B that don't match all of the compared columns.

I've looked at doing a left join function from recommendations, but can't quite figure it out.

Please help!

Comment: Show us what you've tried and tell us what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` or `not exists` for this.  Here is one method:

```
select b.*
from tableb as b
where not exists (select 1
                  from tablea as a
                  where a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 = b.col3
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

```
Select b.col1,b.col2,b.col3 from 

tableb b left outer join tablea a 

on ( b.col1 != a.co11 and b.col2 != a.co12  and b.col3 != a.co13 )
```

Comment: Pretty sure your and should be ors instead.  That way if any columns don't match, you return the row.